# Do I need to water seeds?

Tags: stardew-valley

I know that not watering crops will [slow their growth](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crops#Grow_Times) and eventually kill them. Does this apply to freshly planted seeds as well? Is there any benefit to watering seeds I just planted or should I wait until they sprout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The seeds will turn into seedlings the next day, if you water them. So it is recommended to water in order to start growth immediately.

Comment: So if I don't water freshly planted seeds, will they die or just take longer to turn into seedlings?

Comment: It will just take longer to turn into seedlings; delayed one day if you water the next day.